# How can I make a reusable WordPress function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a routine that generates a list of related posts, intended for use in single.php:

```
  //for use in the loop, list 5 post titles related to first tag on current post
  $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
  if ($tags) {
      echo 'Related Posts';
      $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
      $args=array(
        'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'showposts'=>5,
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
       );
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

          <?php
        endwhile;
      }
    wp_reset_query();
   }
```

What do I need to do to add this into function.php so that I can call this function in the WordPress post editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `$post` variable is global in WP, you can simply do the following:

```
function doStuff()
{
    global $post;

    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
    if ($tags) {
    echo 'Related Posts';
    $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
    $args=array(
        'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'showposts'=>5,
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        <?php
        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply put `<?php doStuff() ?>` in your template.

Note however, that functions using `$post` must only be used within [“The Loop”](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: or you could just pass $post->ID and not use global since you don't use any of the primary post in the function.